# Manifold with Atlases of different Dimension

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Given a set M with a topology, will two different Atlases $A_1$ & $A_2$ have same dimension? Does the following argument hold : -

If at a point $x$ i have a chart $(U,\phi)$ in $A_1$ $(U,\psi)$ in $A_2$, then $\psi \circ \phi^{-1}$ is a homeomorphism (we cannot claim this is diffeomorphism. right ?). And we cannot have homeomorphism between eculidean space of different dimensions.

Since the last fact used is not easy to prove, is there any other proof for the original question ?

Comment: If you mean topological manifolds, then yes the transition maps are only homeomorphisms. If you want to use differentiable manifolds then you have diffeomorphisms. For the first case, as far as I know there is no "easy" proof.

Comment: No, $A_1$ & $A_2$ are differential structures. I think even then we cannot claim $\psi\circ\phi^{-1}$ to be diffeomorphism as $\psi$ and $\phi$ come from two different atlases.

Comment: Ah, I see, not the question I was expecting. Well, since there exist manifolds that are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic (Milnor's famous example), that means a homeomorphism is the most you can ask.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of manifold usually contains mentioning of the dimension, which is then, fixed. Your question makes sense in case of manifolds which are not connected, in that case one could be tempted to allow different dimensions for different component, but this is not what you will usually see. For connected component the dimension is fixed anyway, due to invariance of domain as indicated by your question. Whether invariance of domain is trivial or not is not of importance for this.

Comment: thanks thomas, but i think it is not the case that one has to define dimension even for a connected manifold. It's only the dimension of chart that we know, and it can be proved to be same for each chart due to compatibility condition of $\phi \circ \psi^{-1}$ being $C^\infty$ where $(U,\phi)$ and $(V,\psi)$ are two charts with $U \cap V \neq \Phi$

Answer (score 1):

If a chart maps to $\mathbb{R}^p$ and another maps to $\mathbb{R}^q$, their differential must be a map $\mathbb{R}^p\to \mathbb{R}^q$ with a two sided inverse. Since the differential is a linear map, having a two sided inverse equals being an isomorphism, which requires $p = q$.

The topological case is much harder, though, because you can't reduce your problem to linear algebra.